# Drools 5.1.1 unexpected Accumulate and Collect behavior

Tags: java, jboss, rabbitmq, drools, spring-amqp

I'm using Spring AMQP to read messages from RabbitMQ.  After a message is read it's deserialized into one header (parent) object and multiple detail (child) objects.  Those facts are then inserted into a Drools stateless rule session.  Finally, the updated facts are inserted into a database.

I have several rules that will aggregate the detail facts using either the collect or accumulate functions.  Here's an example.

```
rule "Header.TotalDuration" 
when 
    h : BresHeader() 
    n : Number() 
            from accumulate( d : BresDetail(willSendToInvoice==true, 
                                            uniqueConfID ==   h.uniqueConfID),
                             sum(d.Duration) ) 
then 
    h.TotalDuration = new Integer(n.longValue()); 
    System.out.println("[TotalDuration] rule ran"); 
end
```

If I run this once (reading in one message) in jUnit, the TotalDuration is calculated correctly.  If I run it in tomcat (continuously reading messages) the values for TotalDuration are not correct and increase after each each pass (message is grabbed, rules ran, facts persisted, repeat) and I can't figure out why.

Can anyone shed light on this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you have a `static` variable that continues pass in the facts in from previous messages to new messages.